# Which ecommerce carts support bitcoin with the biggest user base?

Tags: ecommerce

I'm looking to start up a ecommerce solution and wanted to know which ecommerce software is best suited to accept bitcoin which also has the most community support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a standalone cart (no payment processor intermediary) maybe the OSCommerce cart?

Here's the full list:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category:Shopping_Cart_Interfaces

The most widely used cart though probably is the Wordpress ECommerce cart plugin through BitPay:

- https://github.com/bitpay

Answer (score 1):

I went with drupal commerce as it gave me the flexibility I needed. I'm able to add in logic via the gui using the drupal rules module. Currently I have it setup where all international orders must pay in bitcoin and if an order is above $300 they have to pay in btc.

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bitcoin - This is if you want to link it with your own bitcoin daemon

https://www.drupal.org/project/bitpay - I used this one as Bitpay has a easy setup.